# Elm create-elm-app Error: Problem with the flags given to your Elm program on initialization. Json.Decode.oneOf failed in the following 2 ways

Tags: model, elm, flags

I am working on an elm app, and when I try to change the `Model` to anything other than `{}` I get the error

```
Error: Problem with the flags given to your Elm program on initialization. Json.Decode.oneOf failed in the following 2 ways: (1) Problem with the given value: undefined Expecting null (2) Problem with the given value: undefined Expecting an INT
```

The error is reproduced [here](https://ellie-app.com/cSKPn5Z6btda1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `init` is expecting `Maybe Model` but in HTML section of Ellie you’re not passing in a flags.

There are two options, you can either handle the flags, or remove the flags.

**To keep parsing flags:**
You’ll want to change Elm.Main.init({ node: document.querySelector('main') }) to be

```
var app = Elm.Main.init({
  node: document.querySelector('main'),
  flags: <some value>
});
```

It’s also usually recommended to change your flags to be Json.Decode.Value and manually decode them
So your init would become

```
init : Value -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
  case Json.Decode.decodeValue flagDecoder flags of
    Ok decodedFlags -> ...
    Err err -> ...
```

that way you can handle the flags being invalid or missing.

**Remove Flag parsing**

The common way is to us the unit type `()`.
So your main becomes

```
main : Program () Model Msg
```

and

init becomes

```
init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
```